# for hand in the sentence

Tags: word-usage

Tom arranged for hand delivery of the document to the school.
`for hand` in the sentence confuse me.
1.Tom himself arranged delivery of the document to the school.
The action `arrange` was done by tom himself.
The action `delivery of the document to the school` was done by others ,not tom.

2.The actions both `arrange` and `delivery of the document to the school` were done by tom himself.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Tom 【arranged for】【 hand delivery】 of the document to the school.

Answer (score 1):

> Tom arranged for hand delivery of the document to the school.

This implies Tom arranged for the document to be hand-delivered by someone else. Hand-delivery is to take something in person to the recipient or send it using a courier rather than shipping it.

While it is possible Tom arranged his own plans to hand-deliver a document himself, the usage of "arrange" feels out of place in this context.